# cannot execute multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to execute multiple queries, but something is wrong.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 0);

$sql = "
UPDATE tmatria SET par = " . $newpar . ", inde = " . $newinde . " WHERE id =" . $cutid . ";
SELECT * FROM tmatria ORDER BY inde ASC;
SET @i := 0;
UPDATE tmatria SET inde = @i := @i + 1;
";

try {
    $db->exec($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

I want update some columns, then sort table by `inde` column and finally set `inde` values to `1 2 3...`

I think lines `UPDATE tmatria SET par...` and `SELECT * FROM tmatria ORDER BY inde ASC;` are critical, but cannot see what's wrong.

Any help?

Comment: That is absolutely ***not*** how you include variables in a query.

Comment: What is happening when you try to run this? Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: @RobertColumbia there is no any error message.

Comment: @bonaca what happens then?

Comment: @RobertColumbia `inde` column is set to `1 2 3...` before table is sorted by `inde` column. In fact it is not sorted at all.

Comment: @Ben, the line with variables works fine and that is not my question.

Comment: this seems VERY similar to a question you posed earlier

Comment: To my weak and feeble mind this seems peculiar. The initial update statement sets a particular value for the column `inde` for a specific ID ( along with other columns too ), the `SELECT` statement does nothing and then you set a variable `@i=0` and update the `inde` column for ALL records to 1 - thus overwriting what was updated in the first statement

Comment: @RamRaider, no, he first updates one row with a new inde value. Then he wants to renumber all the rows, to ensure that they have consecutive values. The expression `@i := @i + 1` is evaluated for each row, thus `@i` increments as a side-effect as the update proceeds through the table.

Comment: :) thanks :@BillKarwin, I learned something today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some fundamental misunderstanding about how to use SQL. You do a SELECT ... ORDER BY, and then you expect the following UPDATE to obey the same ordering. The UPDATE is ordering the table in its natural order, it doesn't pay attention to the SELECT query at all.

And as a matter of coding, there's no need or benefit to executing multiple SQL statements in one call. PDO permits it, but it's not a good habit. You should execute one SQL statement per call. As long as you use the same db connection, the session variable `@i` will retain its value.

Also use prepared queries when you want to combine PHP variables with a SQL statement; don't concatenate PHP variables into your SQL string.

```
try {
    $sql = "UPDATE tmatria SET par = ?, inde = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$newpar, $newinde, $cutid]); 
    $sql = "SET @i := 0";
    $db->exec($sql);
    $sql = "UPDATE tmatria SET inde = @i := @i + 1 ORDER BY inde ASC";
    $db->exec($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

It also looks like you're trying to renumber `inde` after every update, to force that column to have consecutive values. This will get slower and slower the more rows you have in the table, right?

You should reconsider why you need that column to have consecutive values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your queries to PDO one at a time. You can still use variables like `@i`, because PDO will run your queries in order. But it won't run a mess of queries in one call.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Could you give me an example ?